# set join statement result to class model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to set a join statement result to model view.

but the problem: there are 4 names fields to search but only first name is mandatory the other are not.

**LINQ statment**:

```
public static List<Laborer> getLaborerByName(int? laborOfficeNo, long? componyNo, string firstName, string secondName, string thirdName, string fourthName)
{
    var queryGetLaborerByName = (from c in db.Compny
                                 join x in db.Laborer on c.PK_componyId equals x.FK_componyId
                                 where c.SequenceNumber == componyNo
                                    && c.FK_LaborOfficeId == laborOfficeNo
                                 select x);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
        queryGetLaborerByName = queryGetLaborerByName.Where(pr => pr.FirstName.Contains(firstName));
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(secondName))
        queryGetLaborerByName = queryGetLaborerByName.Where(pr => pr.SecondName.Contains(secondName));
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdName))
        queryGetLaborerByName = queryGetLaborerByName.Where(pr => pr.ThirdName.Contains(thirdName));
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdName))
        queryGetLaborerByName = queryGetLaborerByName.Where(pr => pr.FourthName.Contains(fourthName));
    if (queryGetLaborerByName.ToList().Count > 0)
    {
        return queryGetLaborerByName.ToList();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**ViewModle:**

```
        public string LaborerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string LaborerSecondName { get; set; }
        public string LaborerThirdName { get; set; }
        public string LaborerFourthName { get; set; }
```

**How to make it Work in Model with Maintain the serach filtering.**

I hope its Clear to understand

**it seem not understandable.
What I want is KEEP the search filtering. which accept theses scenario:**

1. Search By First Name only.Result: will be all the employee has First name match the name was entered.
2. Search By First Name and Second Name.Result :will be all the employee name has First name and second name match the names was entered.
3. Search By First Name and Second Name and third name.Result :will be all the employee name has First name and second name and third name match the names was entered.
4. Search By First Name and Second Name and third name and fourth name.Result :will be all the employee name has First and second  and third and fourth names match the names was entered. So here most of will show the name of the wanted employee.

Comment: I'm unable to see what the issue is with your code. Are you experiencing an error? Does the result of calling `queryGetLaborerByName.ToList();` not match what you expected?

Comment: the issue is how to keep the search filtering works fine when assign the result to list<ViewModel>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use a or condition such that allows a match or has empty string:

```
(SecondName equals SecondName or SecondName equals EmptyString) and
(ThirdName equals  ThirdName or ThirdName equals EmptyString) and
(ForthdName equals  ForthName or ForthdName equals EmptyString) and
```

In effect if SecondName, ThirdName, ForthName is not empty and does not match then the row will not return since it does not match and is not empty.

```
public class One
{
    public static List<Laborer> getLaborerByName(int? laborOfficeNo, long? componyNo, string firstName, string secondName, string thirdName, string fourthName)
    {
        var queryGetLaborerByName = (from c in db.Compny
                                    join x in db.Laborer on c.PK_componyId equals x.FK_componyId
                                    where c.SequenceNumber == componyNo
                                        && c.FK_LaborOfficeId == laborOfficeNo
                                        && c.FirstName.Equals(firstName)  // Force First Name match
                                        && (c.SecondName.Equals(secondName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.SecondName)  // Accepts SecondName Match or SecondName is EmptyString
                                        && (c.ThirdName.Equals(thirdName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ThirdName) // Accepts ThirdName Match or ThirdName is EmptyString
                                        && (c.ForthNameName.Equals(forthName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ForthName)  // Accepts ForthName Match or ForthName is EmptyString                                                                                                                  
                                    select x);

        return queryGetLaborerByName;
    }
}
```

**Revised**

```
    public class One
    {
        public static List<Laborer> getLaborerByName(int? laborOfficeNo, long? componyNo, string firstName, string secondName, string thirdName, string fourthName)
        {
            var queryGetLaborerByName = (from c in db.Compny
                                        join x in db.Laborer on c.PK_componyId equals x.FK_componyId
                                        where c.SequenceNumber == componyNo
                                            && c.FK_LaborOfficeId == laborOfficeNo
                                            && c.FirstName.Equals(firstName)  // Force First Name match
                                            && (c.SecondName.Equals(secondName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(secondName)  // Accepts SecondName Match or SecondName is EmptyString
                                            && (c.ThirdName.Equals(thirdName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdName) // Accepts ThirdName Match or ThirdName is EmptyString
                                            && (c.ForthNameName.Equals(forthName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(forthName)    // Accepts ForthName Match or ForthName is EmptyString                                                                                                                  
                                        select x);

            return queryGetLaborerByName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but its only accept the case of enters the full name . not other cases.

Comment: @user3509742,  Made revision. Here I think it should work.  I changed the condition so that if the user does not enter the last three names it will match only on first name.  If they enter first and forth then it will ignore second and third names in the query.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE : This is not an attempt as an answer, but I really had to mention this.

Your code currently has

```
if (queryGetLaborerByName.ToList().Count > 0)
{
    return queryGetLaborerByName.ToList();
}
```

I strongly suggest you end the method with

`return queryGetLaborerByName.ToList();`

and let the callee deal with the fact there are not items in the collection. Calling `.ToList()` twice, plus a call to `Count()` (use `Any()` as an alternative for finding out if a list contains any items. `Count()` will iterate through every single item, whilst `Any()` stops once the first item is encountered.) is not best practice.